# Paypal IPN notification not being sent

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

At this moment in time I have no ssl cert. I have just ordered it and I need to set up a new web server as currently while I build this app I'm using my existing server with an addon domain. When I have finished it i will get my new dedicated server and SSL cert installed.

I am using the following button:

```
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1111">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="123456">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="[my-business-paypal-email]">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.[mywebsiteURL].com/gdpripnh-exec.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.[mywebsiteURL].com/upgrade.php">

<input type="submit"   border="0" name="submit" value="Buy Now!" />

</form>
```

I have setup my Paypal IPN url in my Paypal developer control panel, as it didn't work I added the notify_url to the button.

I tried the ipn testing simulator andd got this error response:

> IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.

I am using this IPN script

```
 <?php

// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


define("LOG_FILE", "./giggdipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

            // Split response headers and payload
            list($headers, $res) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res, 2);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
     $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
     $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
     $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
     $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
     $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
     $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
     $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
     $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/addme/config/connect.php');

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/global-functions.php');




 if (strtolower($payment_status) == 'completed'){

 //good stuff happens here


}else{

//bad stuff happens here

}

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
exit();
?>
```

So I press the paypal button and get redirected to the paypal sandbox page where I login with a test account and make the payment. The payment is successful and I get returned to the page which I have specified. No IPN activity whatsoever.

Where I have put `//good stuff happens here` I am collecting information and entering it into my SQL database. I am also updating a log file which i use for testing. But nothing is happening.

I am baffled because i did get a log in giggdipn.log just one time. it stated:

> [2016-02-26 17:27 America/Chicago] Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: SSL connect error

I deleted it and tried again, just to see and now I do not get it at all.

So I googled and tried adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

still I get nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the url you provided for the ipn response is correct and accessible from the outside world?

Comment: down vote
accept
You are going to think im stupid!!! This proves i am!!!! i totally forgot im redirecting all traffic using htaccess that doesnt come from my ip address! i have just gone to bed, in the morning i will create a rule to allow access to the ipn. Im guessing that must be the problem. I will update you when i do it. Cant believe i totally overlooked that and spent nearly half a day on this!! Thank you so much i can sleep well now!

Comment: Yes it works fine now, i have completed the payment section. :-) I had to set up my ssl cert first tho.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Url provides for the IPN response is accessible to the outside world.

Comment: Added an access rule and now i am getting my log file updated however i am getting the error; [2016-02-27 02:59 America/Chicago] Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: SSL connect error - I am now in the process of setting up my dedicated server and will install my extended ssl cert. when its done i expect i will have solved this but i will update it either way.... cross fingers for me as time is running out!

Comment: The simplest answers are sometimes the hardest to find. I suspect the ssl error is something to do with the commented cacert code block but you won't need it when your ssl is set up.